# Most practical way to add a value to a particular list, based on a variable

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

The title may sound a bit weird, but the situation is not so much.

I have some lists.
Here they are initialized (global variables):

```
sensor0, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3 = ([] for i in range(4))
```

Now we have a variable that indicates the list that i can insert data to. Let's say it's `selector = 3`.

This means i should append() my value to the `sensor3` list.

What is the most practical way to do this in python?
If it was a C style language, i would use a `switch-case`.

But there is no `switch-case` syntax in python. Of course i could do multiple `if`s, but this seems not the best way to do it.

I wonder, since there is only one letter to the lists that change everytime, perhaps there is a better way to select the proper list to `append()` to, based on the `selector` variable.

Comment: Why not just have it as a list of lists (`sensors = [[] for i in range(4)]`), then `sensors[selector].append(data)`?

Comment: ... or a dictionary?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you! The first command is the initialization right? But something that came up, is that i want to pass all those lists as global variables to a function. Can i do that with a one liner as well?

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, the first bit is replacing your initialization. And you could just have the function accept a 2D list, or do `your_func(*sensors)`. `*` unpack the inner lists into the argument list (the function would need to accept four arguments in this case).

Comment: @AndrejKesely Not sure i understood....

Comment: @Carcigenicate I kinda lost it.....

Comment: @Carcigenicate If i go back to your first comment. I have the new initialization like you said. I have a way to append to the corresponding array. All of this is fine. But is there a way to pass the list of list as a global var to the function? Perhaps `global sensors`?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine, but globals are almost always the wrong design choice. If a function needs data, pass the data into the function as arguments. Code generally makes much more sense when you avoid globals. And also, don't use `eval` as suggested by the answer. It won't cause a ton of problems here, but it'll make your code slower, and opens up a massive security hole for very little gain.

Comment: I am using a tkinter application, and i using arguments will complicate the situation. A lot of button related functions have to have access to that data. I understand that passing it as a global var, is not the best practice, but if i wanted to stick to it, how would i declare the list of lists as global to my function?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, use eval

```
sensor0, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3 = ([] for i in range(4))
sensor3 = 20
selector =3 
result = eval("sensor"+str(selector))
print(result)
```

But using a list may be a better option.
**Using List**

```
sensor = [[] for i in range(4)]
selector = 3
sensor[selector] = 20
print(sensor[selector])
```

Comment: Thank you. But in your second code snippet, are you sure the first line (`sensor = [c[] for i in range(4)]`) is correct? I typed it in the REPL and i got  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user1584421 I accidently typed c before []. Have edited the answer, should work now.

Comment: Thank you but this is not a good solution because i cannot append() new values to the list. When i tried `data= 100; sensor[selector].append(data)`, i got `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: That is because you assigned 20 to sensor[3]. This means your sensor variable holds ```[[], [], [], 20]``` And sensor[3] is no longer a list.

You need to edit the question and explain your problem better.